# Are we always notified of posted answers while we write ours?

Tags: support

After I had posted [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107907/3217) to a question, I noticed that Mariano had posted [his](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107906/3217) three minutes before, but I had not been advised.
However, sometimes I *am* advised and on MO I am *always* advised.
So, when does one get advised and according to what criterion?
Mariano thinks it depends on the position of the planets, an explanation that I like, but I wanted to know if there was a rival theory.

Comment: By advised I suppose you mean notified?

Comment: A more down to earth explanation could be that [the tubes of the intarweb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes) were clogged? `:-)` But yes, I also see this every now and then.

Comment: @Asaf: right,corrected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not notified when posting from the iOS

Comment: I have been notified several times today. So much the better.

Comment: Presumably the new answer notification feature polls the site at some fixed interval for new answers.  If this interval is fairly long (say 10 minutes) then it could be that it just depends on timing.